# Como calcular IOF de cartão de crédito internacional?

Tags: c#

Alguém já precisou alguma vez implementar função de cálculo de IOF de cartão de crédito internacional em sistemas que poderia me dar essa ajuda? Preciso saber as regras de como calcular. Grata!

Comment: Não é só multiplicar por 1.0638?

Comment: Math, deu certo os meus cálculos conforme a sua ajuda. Como faço para saber essa regra e manter sempre atualizada quando houver alteração nessa taxa?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static bool Mod10Check(string creditCardNumber)
{
     //// check whether input string is null or empty
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(creditCardNumber))
     {
         return false;
     }

      //// 1.   Starting with the check digit double the value of every other digit 
      //// 2.   If doubling of a number results in a two digits number, add up
      ///   the digits to get a single digit number. This will results in eight single digit numbers                    
      //// 3. Get the sum of the digits
      int sumOfDigits = creditCardNumber.Where((e) => e >= '0' && e <= '9')
                .Reverse()
                .Select((e, i) => ((int)e - 48) * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2))
                .Sum((e) => e / 10 + e % 10);


       //// If the final sum is divisible by 10, then the credit card number
       //   is valid. If it is not divisible by 10, the number is invalid.            
       return sumOfDigits % 10 == 0;            
}
```

Pelo que percebi a minha resposta não é mais correcta por isso aqui fica uma correção mantenho a outra para referência futura.

**Pelo que percebi (e sou de Portugal, não temos IOF), o imposto actualmente é de 1,10% sobre o valor total.**

Tem duas formas de calcular com agravamento ou incluido no valor total da compra.

1) Com agravamento

```
 var valor = 100;
 var total = valor + (valor * 0.0638);
```

Ou seja 106,38.

2) Sem Agravamento

```
 var valor = 100;
 var total = valor - (valor * 0.0638);
```

Ou seja 100 sendo que o valor a pagar sem IOF é de 93.62

Página de referência https://www.jafezasmalas.com/como-fugir-do-iof-nas-compras-e-saques-no-exterior/

Comment: `If the final sum is divisible by 10, then the credit card number is valid` < Isso é um algoritmo para verificar se o número do cartão é ou não válido, a pergunta pede outra coisa completamente diferente.

Comment: O que está a pedir e o check digit e é precisamente isso que lhe mandei

Comment: Mas IOF é o nome de um imposto

Comment: Mas o que o Imposto tem a ver com o Cartao de Credito?

Comment: Quando se faz compras no exterior se paga IOF, já agora o que o autor da pergunta quer não consegui entender também. Provavelmente por isso a pergunta tá com negativos D:

Comment: Pho3nix, obrigada pela explicação e pelo exemplo no código. Eu precisava só da regra de cálculo do IOF para aplicar no sistema já pronto e incluir mais essa taxa. Você ajudou até mais que isso. Sabe se existe alguma forma ou órgão onde eu possa sempre manter atualizada quando esse valor da taxa de 6,38% for atualizado?